# Azure B2C Custom Register Page Validation Issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've followed the steps for UI customization referenced [here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) 
I'm able to successfully register and login. The issue i'm experiencing is that the input:invalid css classes are being added to all registration page inputs when I access the SignUp policy directly resulting in all input fields to have an error state:

[image]

However, if I access the page by the SignInSignUp policy (i.e. clicking on register link on custom login page), this does not occur.
Here is the [SignInSignUp Policy URL](https://login.microsoftonline.com/miamibeachflgov.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ResortTaxSignInSignUp&client_id=fc47cc67-88db-4591-9e35-ca238e4bed08&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login), and this is the [SignUp Policy Url](https://login.microsoftonline.com/miamibeachflgov.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ResortTaxSignUp&client_id=fc47cc67-88db-4591-9e35-ca238e4bed08&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login)

Comment: Can you share the sign-up page url by chance?  Curious...

Comment: @spottedmahn Thanks. Updated question with both policy Urls.

Comment: Bad request response on unified one.

Comment: Edited it again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once they finally [allow JavaScript](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br), you can work around this.

I suspect the problem is related to [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15459522-wait-until-submission-to-display-errors).